# Populating a matrix with multiple columns from an existing matrix matched against a data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of data, **m**:

```
                 12345      12348
2011-05-13          NA 0.18001079
2011-05-16 0.056780170 0.15526660
2011-05-17 0.005848973 0.17363081
2011-05-18 0.096594178 0.20114677
2011-05-19 0.038920055 0.15744843
```

And I have a data frame, **df**:

```
id    date
12345 2011-05-13
12345 2011-05-18
12348 2011-05-13
12348 2011-05-19
```

I would like to add to my data frame **df** a new entry **e** (I think it's another matrix but I'm not sure about the terminology) which contains the values from my matrix for the 20 useful days before and after the date in df. By 'useful day' I mean one that appears in rownames(m).

```
id    date       e
12345 2011-05-13 [40x1 double matrix]
12345 2011-05-18 [40x1 double matrix]
12348 2011-05-13 [40x1 double matrix]
12348 2011-05-19 [40x1 double matrix]
```

I can use `shift.down` and `shift.up` from matrixcalc to find the 20 'useful days' before and after the current day, and I can use `match(df$date,rownames(m)` to find the index into m that I need.

However here, I'm stuck. What's the best way to create and fill the new entry **e** so it contains the information I need? I'm aware there will be NA entries when -20 or +20 'useful days' falls outside of the range I have info for, and there are also NA entries within **m** anyway.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It is great that you provided sample data for us to look at here, but it can be a pain to recreate the dataset in R manually. You'll get faster answers if you provide code to recreate the sample data you are working with. For example, if you have the `matrix` m, then you can just type `dput(m)` and you will get the commands to recreate the matrix exactly, which you could paste here. Similarly, you could have provided the code that you used to get the 20 'useful days' so we could quickly recreate your situation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the dput command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that what you are trying to do overall might be accomplished in a different way, but here is a solution to what you asked.

```
# Create the data
m=matrix(c(NA,0.056780170,0.005848973,0.096594178,0.038920055,0.18001079,0.15526660,0.1736081,0.20114677,0.15744843),ncol=2)
colnames(m) = c(12345,12348)
rownames(m) = c('2011-05-13','2011-05-16','2011-05-17','2011-05-18','2011-05-19')

df=data.frame(id=c(12345,12345,12348,12348),date=as.Date(c('2011-05-13','2011-05-18','2011-    05-13','2011-05-19')))
```

The idea is to first create a function that returns the matrix for a single pair of id and date. I don't think you need the `shift.up` or `shift.down` functions from `matrixCalc`, but you could use it if you find it easier.

```
# Create a function that returns a matrix for a single row    
get.matrix = function(id,date,shift=20) {
   row=match(as.character(date),rownames(m))
   rows=max(1,row-shift):min(nrow(m),row+shift)
   m[rows,as.character(id),drop=F] # The drop=F means that it won't be reduced to a vector
}
```

Note that the function will usually return 41 rows, not 40. Also, if the it is an "early" or "late" date, then it might return much less.

```
# Apply that function to all rows
df$e=mapply(get.matrix,id=df$id,date=df$date,SIMPLIFY=F)
```

After you make the function, you can just apply it to every row in your data frame.